Unable to successfully build OpensimRT
Hello I've been wanting to get a GRF prediction software called OpensimRT which works with the biomechanical simulation software Opensim to work. The github for OpensimRT is as follows: https://github.com/mitkof6/OpenSimRT
I have failed to get this software to work and have been hoping someone can get it working and explain how. The file continuous-integration.yml is supposed to build it but fails to get the software working: https://github.com/mitkof6/OpenSimRT/blob/master/.github/workflows/continuous-integration.yml
I have tried to build the software on windows 10, windows 11, and Linux (specifically Ubuntu 18.04 on windows vm) and can't get it to function.
I'm hoping to get the software to launch and load it with motion capture files.
